# Codeigniter Community AUth Use of undefined constant USE_SSL

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am on `Codeigniter 3`. I recently installed `Community Auth` and I am receiving error:

> Use of undefined constant USE_SSL - assumed 'USE_SSL'".

When I change the code to to `USE_SSL`, the error is resolved but I want to make sure that this is the correct solution and that `USE_SSL` is not some global variable or function versus a constant but I do not see anything on the `Codigniter` forum about this.

Comment: Somewhere in code you have `USE_SSL` instead `'USE_SSL'` or vice versa. When defining constant you have to use quotation marks. When using you use it without quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Yes the first step must be
    $config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
and second in /application/config/hooks.php
add these line

```
$hook['pre_system'] = array(
   'function' => 'auth_constants',
   'filename' => 'auth_constants.php',
   'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
$hook['post_system'] = array(
   'function' => 'auth_sess_check',
   'filename' => 'auth_sess_check.php',
  'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I had use hooks disabled in my cofig file.